# How to split the string only get a particular value

Tags: java, string

I have a string, "900.9/6.00%", that I want to split into string only get particular value of "6.00" while taking particular value of "6.0" multiply by 2 of bettingAmount.

```
 bettingAmount : 2.000
 bettingAmount : 900.9/6.00%
```

My Code :

```
String string = "900.9/6.00%";
String[] parts = string.split("/");
String part1 = parts[0]; // 900.9
String part2 = parts[1]; // 6.00%
```

That means the first string will contain the characters before '/', and the second string will contain the characters after '/'. But the problem is i need to get the value only "6.0". How can I do this? Kindly advise

Comment: _"i need to get the value only "6.0"_ What do you mean ? If it's `6.79%`, you want to have `6.7` or something ?

Comment: @MickaëlB yes , if it;s 6.79% , i need to get 6.79%

Comment: If you want to avoid saving an Array var look at my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `substring` based solution

```
String xy="900.9/6.00%";
double result=Double.parseDouble(xy.substring(xy.indexOf("/")+1,xy.indexOf('%')))*2;
System.out.println(" result "+result); // result 12.0
```

same code:

```
String xy="900.9/0.06%";
double result=Double.parseDouble(xy.substring(xy.indexOf("/")+1,xy.indexOf('%')))*2;
System.out.println(" result "+result); // result 0.12
```

Comment: hi , what if i want it to multply the value of 0.06 * 2?

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] parts = string.split("[/%]");
```

Splits on any char / or %.

```
double pct = Double.parseDouble(part2);
pct *= 2; // or such
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
part2 = part2.replace("%", "");
```

It replaces the % with nothing.

Then as Joop suggests you can do:

```
double pct = Double.parseDouble(part2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String valuetoSave = string.split("/")[1]
//valuetoSave = "6.00%"
valuetoSave = valuetoSave.split("%")[0]
//valuetoSave = "6.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think can do this with a regex, but it may a little bit complicated :

```
String REGEX = "^(\\d+\\.\\d+)/(\\d+\\.\\d+)";
String string = "900.9/6.00%";
String part1 = "";
String part2 = "";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
if(m.find()){
        MatchResult mr = m.toMatchResult();
        part1 = mr.group(1)
        part2 = mr.group(2)
}
```

Otherwhise you can just remove "%" before to split your string :

```
String string = "900.9/6.00%";
string = string .replace("%", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @codechat ,

I have amend the code to get the result of 0.12

```
double result=Double.parseDouble(part6.substring(part6.indexOf("/")+1,part6.indexOf('%')))*2/100.0;
        System.out.println(" result "+result); // result 0.12
```

Comment: oh i did not know you wanted to fraction it while calculating ! anyways, good you figured it out yourself :)